# Jquery logics confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic

I want to make a bit of code that will check the value of an input box, count how many letters there are in the input box and if the value is divisable by 4 then to insert a -

Its so when the user is entering a code, in automatically inserts - after every 4 letters :)

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having with understanding this logic?  Can you show us any attempts you have made?  Got any code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where you post your homework and someone will do it for you. Here you make a detailed question, provide the code that YOU wrote and is not working as expected, and people will try to spot the problem and help you. Or you can ask questions about generic programming concepts, but no way anyone will do your homework for you. Flagged.

Comment: I apologise for this then, the answer below is what I was looking for, guess i worded it badly. Im used to coding with PHP and am still learning JQuery. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  if(this.value.replace(/-/g, "").length % 4 == 0) {
     this.value += "-";
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes but assumed aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa was wanted as opposed to aaaa-aaa-aa-a

Comment: thank you, ill give that a go, I wasnt sure if the % operator is valid in jquery :)

Comment: By continuously pressing a key it is not appearing - after every 4 letters.

Comment: @Krish good catch. I guess you could use the `input` event (as long as you don't have to support <= IE8).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in the way you want

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var stringFull = $(this).val();
        if(stringFull.replace(/-/g, "").length % 4 == 0 ){
            $(this).val(stringFull+"-");        
        }       
    });

});
```